# Verifying another account's email on the wrong account results in a merge

Tags: support, merge-accounts

The account that I'm currently on (Cyph) is an **old** account that I want to discard as I never use it. But before I delete it, I wanted to make sure that I could use the email currently associated with it on my new account (GROVER). (It's not actually a new account, I've had it for years, I've just **only** used that one).

So, I changed this account's email address and then verified it - which went fine. Then I changed my new account's email to the one I wanted. *This is where it went wrong*. As I'm currently signed into both accounts on my laptop and PC, I accidentally clicked on the new account's verification code on the device that is logged into the old account (this one).

I didn't think much of it (I obviously got an error and thought I might try again). But then I noticed, on the device which my new account is logged into, I got logged out and **re-logged-in** as *this* account. Even weirder is that the majority of my reputation has also been transferred over. I went from having 21 reputation on this account to 1,942 (I had something like 2,030 on my new one) **and** now my new accounts [**URL**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5859909/grover) is redirecting to a user not found page.

This is super confusing to me, and to make matters worse no matter what email I use, I **always** get logged back into this one. I would really love it if I could get my new account back as it had over 200 questions and answers collectively and are very important to me (as well as over 40 trophies - of which only half have transferred over).

This seems like a major security issue in my opinion and should definitely be looked at.

Comment: You have access to all of your posts and all of your badges still exist. What makes you think you lost access to anything?

Comment: @animuson Didn't say I've lost access. But I have lost trophies, 100 reputation and the right to edit posts without moderation. And not only that, this **shouldn't be happening anyway.**

Comment: @animuson Oh whoops just read you said posts. Yeah, I can't see any of my posts currently. This account seems to keep refreshing with new data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First off, we do not officially support operating multiple accounts and trying to do odd things to transfer credentials between different accounts has always been highly discouraged by us because it can result in this very thing happening. The automatic merge system is in place to assist users who get confused about how they registered on the site. When a user directly confirms via the confirmation links that they do own both accounts, we merge them together automatically to keep everything in one place for them.

Upon a merge, all of the posts and comments get moved to the profile on the lower AccountId, and then triggers a reputation recalculation. Any votes that would now be towards yourself are hard deleted, which can cause your reputation to drop. If you had the association bonus on both accounts, you'd also notice an immediate loss of 100 since you can't have the bonus twice.

Badges are not copied over on a merge. Instead, they will simply get re-awarded to you the next time the relevant badge processes run, assuming you are still eligible to receive them.

All of your stuff is still available on [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6425936/cyph?tab=topactivity) and you are indeed [receiving your badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6425936/cyph?tab=activity&sort=badges) again.

Comment: I'm aware :). I started this account a while back and forgot the credentials to it until recently when I found the password hidden away on an old device. This account had my main email connected to it so I always wanted to transfer the email and disable this account. This answer helped clear some things up; didn't know an account merge was possible and also have never seen it done before, so I thought it might just be a [very strange] bug that's gone unnoticed which needed to be patched.